# How to use MaterialUI's Mobile-Stepper in HypserStack?

Tags: ruby, reactjs, material-ui, hyperstack

I try to use the mobile-stepper component (https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/#mobile-stepper-progress) in Hyperstack but I get this error:

`` Failed prop type: Invalid prop `nextButton` supplied to `MobileStepper`, expected a ReactNode.
    in MobileStepper ``

It renders just the progress bar but no buttons.

Tried various ways i.e.:

```
Mui.MobileStepper( variant: "progress", steps: 6, position: "static",
                   nextButton: lambda { Mui.Button(size: "small") {'next'} },
                   backButton: lambda { Mui.Button(size: "small") {'back'} })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass a full ReactNode to the nextButton and backButton props. You also need to convert the component to native javascript. You can call `to_n` on any Hyperstack component to convert it to a native react class.

```rb
Mui.MobileStepper( variant: "progress", steps: 6, position: "static",
                   nextButton: Mui.Button(size: "small") {'next'}.to_n,
                   backButton: Mui.Button(size: "small") {'back'}.to_n)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does seem to work but I have one issue: it somehow render 2 addition "next", "back" buttons on top of the component, can't figure out why

Comment: @chiwowahh I think its because you need to add `.as_node` so that the component does not render - `Mui.Button(size: "small") {'back'}.as_node.to_n)`